# Calculate distance between latitude and longitude in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

I have 4 columns in my dataframe containing the following data:

```
Start_latitude<br>
Start_longitude<br>
Stop_latitude<br>
Stop_longitude<br>
```

I need to compute distance between the latitude longitude pair and create a new column with the distance computed.

I came across a package (geopy) which can do this for me. But I need to pass a tuple to geopy. How do i apply this function (geopy) across the dataframe in pandas for all the records?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd recommend you use pyproj instead of geopy. geopy relies on online services whereas pyproj is local (meaning it will be faster and won't rely on an internet connection) and more transparent about its methods (see [here](http://proj4.org/geodesic.html) for instance), which are based on the Proj4 codebase that underlies essentially all open-source GIS software and, probably, many of the web services you'd use.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyproj import Geod

wgs84_geod = Geod(ellps='WGS84') #Distance will be measured on this ellipsoid - more accurate than a spherical method

#Get distance between pairs of lat-lon points
def Distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):
  az12,az21,dist = wgs84_geod.inv(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2) #Yes, this order is correct
  return dist

#Create test data
lat1 = np.random.uniform(-90,90,100)
lon1 = np.random.uniform(-180,180,100)
lat2 = np.random.uniform(-90,90,100)
lon2 = np.random.uniform(-180,180,100)

#Package as a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat1':lat1,'lon1':lon1,'lat2':lat2,'lon2':lon2})

#Add/update a column to the data frame with the distances (in metres)
df['dist'] = Distance(df['lat1'].tolist(),df['lon1'].tolist(),df['lat2'].tolist(),df['lon2'].tolist())
```

PyProj has some documentation [here](https://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/pyproj.Geod-class.html).

Comment: The issue is that I am unable to install pyproj. I get an error saying installation failed. It also asks me to install visual basic

Comment: Are you using [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)? It's one of the more sane ways of trying to live with Windows.

Comment: It was missing Visual C++. Managed to install it. Code works great! Thanks! Just curious to know how is this calculating the distance? It draws a straight line between two points?

Comment: @Harikrishna: What do you mean by a "straight-line"? Through a Euclidean 3-space that would be too short. A great circle is the shortest-distance on a sphere; however, the Earth is on oblate spheroid. The method used by Proj4 is drawn from GeographicLib (see [here](http://proj4.org/geodesic.html)), uses the WGS84 ellipsoid, and is accurate to ~15nm. I believe it is is based on `C. F. F. Karney, Algorithms for gedesics, J. Geodesy ‘’‘87’‘’(1), 43-55 (2013), DOI: 10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z; geo-addenda.html.`

Comment: @Harikrishna: If you feel this answer was helpful, feel free to upvote it by clicking the up-arrow to its left. If you feel it was the best answer to your question you can click the outline of a checkmark by the answer.

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation of geopy: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy. You can do this by doing:

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty

# Define the two points
start = (start_latitute, start_longitude)
stop = (stop_latitude, stop_longitude)

# Print the vincenty distance
print(vincenty(start, stop).meters)

# Print the great circle distance
print(great_circle(start, stop).meters)
```

Combining this with Pandas. Assuming you have a dataframe `df`. We first create the function:

```
def distance_calc (row):
    start = (row['start_latitute'], row['start_longitude'])
    stop = (row['stop_latitude'], row['stop_longitude'])

    return vincenty(start, stop).meters
```

And then apply it to the dataframe:

```
df['distance'] = df.apply (lambda row: distance_calc (row),axis=1)
```

Note the axis=1 specifier, that means that the application is done at a row, rather than a column level.

Comment: How do I apply the operation to an entire dataframe in pandas?

Comment: Sorry still typing, i accidentally clicked submit

Comment: Why do i get the error which says that 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rows'

Comment: Thank you! Now I am facing this issue. If I use great_circle to find the distance, it works. But if I use vincenty, it says that vincenty can't be found.

Comment: Are you properly importing vincenty? Also don't forget to mark the question as answered.